# Do waterfalls conserve momentum? If so, how?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

I understand that waterfalls conserve energy, given the fact that the top of a waterfall possesses gravitational potential energy, and as the water is falling from top to bottom, this potential energy is converted into kinetic energy, which, in turn, has high velocity.

How, if in fact, can waterfalls be applied to the conservation of momentum? I have a relatively basic knowledge of physics, but I'm wondering if the answer would be as simple as saying that there is the same amount of mass of water from the top to the bottom of the waterfall, which is also going in the same direction; hence, conservation of momentum.

Comment: Do you mean to conserve momentum while the water falls down?

Comment: @ArnavMahajan Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

The waterfall and the Earth both exert a gravitational force on each other. The change in momentum of the waterfall is exactly equal and opposite to the change in momentum of the Earth. Therefore, momentum is conserved.